# The searchbar works better with Tags than Questions. Explaining this could reduce duplicates and save users time

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Often I will search for a question in a few ways on Stack Overflow and not find anything related.  Then I'll ask the question, and immediately the sidebar fills up with all the things I was looking for.  The reason for this is that it's showing me things related to the tags I used for my question.

This happens constantly and it's most likely due to the fact that language is incredibly diverse and many of us phrase our questions completely differently.  Because of this the search bar works *waayyyyy* better for tags than it does for phrases.

---

If Stack Overflow mentioned somewhere around the search-bar/results that you can and should use tags and implemented a tags in search system, people would be a lot more likely to find things related to what they are looking for.

I just finally figured this out, and the difference between typing a question in the search-bar and listing tags in the search-bar is night and day.

Comment: That only works if the duplicate has similar wordings.  Or are you talking about people who flag them?

Comment: Oh.  That's a cool tip.  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah.  That happens a lot to me too.  Makes sense.  I've gotten in the habit of checking before posting just because those recommendations are so good at showing up right when you think your question is new.

Comment: huh.  You know, every feature request I've made that people didn't like got at least 100 angry views in the first 10 minutes.